# C# disable proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

I set my webbrowser control's proxy using this function

```
    private void SetProxy(string proxy)
    {
        INTERNET_PROXY_INFO IPI = new INTERNET_PROXY_INFO();

        IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
        IPI.lpszProxy = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxy);
        IPI.lpszProxyBypass = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");

        IntPtr intptrStruct = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(IPI));


        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(IPI, intptrStruct, true);
        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(IPI));
    }
```

But I am unable to disable/remove the proxy afterwards, only swap it for another proxy. How can I remove the proxy completely.
Already tried by registry.

No plain links as answers.

Comment: Why dont you just just a webproxy when you want to use a proxy, and when you want to use a connection without a web proxy, just create it without the proxy?

Comment: I'm not using it on a webrequest, I'm using it on a webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

`IPI.dwAccessType` to [`INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385148%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Just wondering, do you know a quick way to know if the proxy kicked in, because I have to refresh the control twice before it takes effect.

Comment: Thanks anyways, just made it sleep 5 sec